# How to submit forms separately without ajax method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

There is a button with title NEWFORM. it is used to create new form when clicked.each form has two button. this two buttons work as submit and has two different request to action page. my codes works good.i am sending my form data via ajax method and i would not like this. i want to change my codes without sending ajax method.is there a way to do that?
here is my snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
          $(".newform").click(function() {
            $(".MyForm")
            .eq(0)
            .clone()
            .show()
            .insertAfter(".MyForm:last");
          });
         //click handler for add from DB 
          $('body').on('click', '.addfromdb', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() // To make sure the form is not submitted 
            var $frm = $(this).closest('.MyForm');
            console.log($frm.serialize());
            $.ajax(
                $(this).attr('formaction'), 
                {
                  method: $frm.attr('method'),
                  data: $frm.serialize()
                }
            );
          });
         //click handler for remove from DB 
         $('body').on('click', '.removefromdb', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() // To make sure the form is not submitted 
            var $frm = $(this).closest('.MyForm');
            console.log($frm.serialize());
            $.ajax(
                $(this).attr('formaction'), 
                {
                  method: $frm.attr('method'),
                  data: $frm.serialize()
                }
            );
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <span class="newform">NEWFORM+</span>
        <div class="all">
          <form class="MyForm" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Aynaz" name="a1" />
            <select name="Avg">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" formaction="first.htm"class="addfromdb">add</button>
             <button type="submit" formaction="secondpage.htm" class="removefromdb">Remove</button>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Remove the click listeners and add `action` url to form tags. `<form>` will submit through default process

Comment: @charlietfl where can i add that? in my html ? or my jquery?

Comment: In the html .... an html form will submit without javascript if you don't prevent it submitting

Comment: @charlietfl the problem is there is multiple action for a form .and i need to use action in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically set the form `action` and not do ajax try changing to:

```
$('body').on('click', '.removefromdb, .addfromdb', function(e) {                 
   var $frm = $(this).closest('.MyForm');
   $frm.attr('action', $(this).attr('formaction'));
});
```

This would update the action and then the form would submit through browser default process

Answer (score 0):

Remove javascript click function and remove formaction attribute from html as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
          $(".newform").click(function() {
            $(".MyForm")
            .eq(0)
            .clone()
            .show()
            .insertAfter(".MyForm:last");
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <span class="newform">NEWFORM+</span>
        <div class="all">
          <form class="MyForm" method="post" action="default.html">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name" value="Aynaz" name="a1" />
            <select name="Avg">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="addfromdb">add</button>
             <button type="submit"class="removefromdb">Remove</button>
          </form>
        </div>
```